# Как сделать, чтобы пагинация и фильтрация работали совместно

Tags: php, wordpress, фильтрация, пагинация

Есть список турниров. У каждого турнира указана дата начала. 
Хочу сделать фильтр для выбора турниров по месяцу и/или году проведения. 
Фильтр вроде получился, но при этом пагинация не работает. Например, турниры за март месяц, он покажет только на второй странице, как и при выводе всех турниров, а первая страница будет пустая.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы и пагинация и фильтрация работали совместно.

```
<form action="http://test.chess22barnaul.ru/tournaments/" method="get">
      <label>Месяц:</label>
      <select name="month">
        <option value="">Any</option>
        <option value="01">январь</option>
        <option value="02">Февраль</option>
        <option value="03">Март</option>
        <option value="04">Апрель</option>                
      </select>
    <button type="submit" name="">search</button>
    </form>  

    <?php                      
          $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
                  $query = new WP_Query( array(                              
                  'post_type' => 'tournaments',
                  'meta_key'       => 'tourn_date-begin',
                  'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',                                           
                  'order'       => 'DESC',
                  'paged'          => $paged,    
                                ) );    
                   while ( $query->have_posts() ):
                   $query->the_post();
                 ?>                       
                 <?php 
                    if($_GET['month'] && !empty($_GET['month'])) { 
                       $month = $_GET['month']; }
                       $datebegin = date('m', strtotime(get_field('tourn_date-begin')));
                       if ( $month == $datebegin)  {
                           ?>
                              <div>информация по турниру</div>
                          <?php endwhile;
                        }
                   ?>          
             <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
```

Comment: Условие фильтра должно быть в запросе, тогда всё получится. https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query

Comment: Вы не правильно написали выборку и неправильно вызываете пагинацию

Comment: А что именно неправильно? Я новичок  и в wp и в php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код, который вам примерно нужен.

Момент 1. Это выборка meta_query в случае, если есть $_GET['month']. Мы выбираем посты, которые с 1-го дня месяца по последний день месяца (meta_query).

Момент 2. the_posts_pagination работает только с глобальным WP_Query. Поэтому для работы нужно изменить global $wp_query а затем вернуть после цикла обратно.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <label>Месяц:</label>
    <select name="month">
        <option value="">Any</option>
        <option value="01">январь</option>
        <option value="02">Февраль</option>
        <option value="03">Март</option>
        <option value="04">Апрель</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="">search</button>
</form>

<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$args  = [
    'post_type' => 'tournaments',
    'meta_key'  => 'tourn_date-begin',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'paged'     => $paged,
];

if ( ! empty( $_GET['month'] ) ) {
    $start_date = new DateTime();
    $start_date->setDate( $start_date->format( 'Y' ), intval( $_GET['month'] ), 1 );
    $end_date = $start_date;
    $end_date->modify( 'last day of this month' );

    $args['meta_query'] = [
        [
            'key'     => 'tourn_date-begin',
            'value'   => $start_date->format( 'Y-m-d' ),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type'    => 'DATE',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'tourn_date-begin',
            'value'   => $end_date->format( 'Y-m-d' ),
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type'    => 'DATE',
        ],
    ];
}
global $wp_query;
$restore_wp_query = $wp_query;

$query    = new WP_Query( $args );
$wp_query = $query;
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ):
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_posts_pagination();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $wp_query = $restore_wp_query;
endif;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Практически получилось. Только переменная $start_date равна $end_date - последнему дню месяца и поэтому не выходят другие турниры месяца ( http://test.chess22barnaul.ru/tournaments-filtr/?month=04)

Comment: @ЮлияЛоскутова можете галочкой отметить ответ, чтобы принять его

Comment: Получилось. Убрала переменную $end_date, вместо нее использую   'value'   => $start_date->format( 'Y-m-t' ). Еще раз спасибо)